# Websraping program issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to the topic and i have hard time trying to figure out why does my program doesnt produce any output

This is the code

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class JobSearchUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, job_offers):
        super().__init__()

        self.job_offers = job_offers

        self.setWindowTitle('Przegląd ofert pracy')
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 600)

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setRowCount(len(self.job_offers))
        self.table.setColumnCount(4)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Tytuł', 'Opis', 'Wymagania', 'Lokalizacja'])

        self.fill_table()

    def fill_table(self):
        row = 0
        for offer in self.job_offers:
            title = QTableWidgetItem(offer['title'])
            title.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.table.setItem(row, 0, title)

            description = QTableWidgetItem(offer['description'])
            self.table.setItem(row, 1, description)

            requirements = QTableWidgetItem(offer['requirements'])
            self.table.setItem(row, 2, requirements)

            location = QTableWidgetItem(offer['location'])
            self.table.setItem(row, 3, location)

            row += 1

def get_job_offers(url_list):
    job_offers = []

    for url in url_list:
        response = requests.get(url)
        html = response.content

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        job_offers_html = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'offer-details'})

        for offer in job_offers_html:
            title = offer.find('a', {'class': 'offer-title__link'}).text.strip()
            description = offer.find('p', {'class': 'offer-company'}).text.strip()
            requirements = offer.find('ul', {'class': 'offer-requirements'}).text.strip()
            location = offer.find('span', {'class': 'offer-labels__location'}).text.strip()

            job_offer = {'title': title, 'description': description, 'requirements': requirements, 'location': location}
            job_offers.append(job_offer)

    return job_offers

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url_list = ['https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/it%20-%20programowanie%20-%20analiza',
                'https://www.infopraca.pl/praca?kw=szukana%20fraza&kt=18']
    job_offers = get_job_offers(url_list)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = JobSearchUI(job_offers)
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And this is the output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re06R.png)

i suppose the issue is in the scraping itself but i cant quite find it
The code doesnt seem to have any bug or error its just the fact that i dont fully grasp the topic and as a working student on quite few diffrent projects i didnt have time or brain power left i hope its some minor mistake

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try not to copy-paste your entire file of code, the time of people here are worth a lot and nobody is going to read through your entire program. Instead, provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or check out this article on [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

When parsing HTML content programmatically, you need to make sure that the content you are looking to find actually is there or you will not get the expected results.

Based on a quick test, at least the first URL in your example does not return HTML content that would have any of the elements you want to find with the classes you have defined in your code. It might be that the second URL also produces no results.

So, the elements and/or classes that you are trying to extract with Beautiful Soup are not there, and that is why you are not getting any job offers.

I would check the web pages closely for what elements and classes they have and change the code to use those. Also, it is always better to first test any code in isolation before integrating it, for example, to a graphical user interface application.